# Change background color for Thresholderd image

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, openvpn, image-thresholding

I have been trying to write a code to extract cracks from an image using thresholding. However, I wanted to keep the background black. What would be a good solution to keep the outer boundary visible and the background black. Attached below is the original image along with the threshold image and the code used to extract this image.

```
import cv2

#Read Image
img = cv2.imread('Original.png')

# Convert into gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Image processing ( smoothing )
# Averaging
blur = cv2.blur(gray,(3,3))

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(blur,145,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
inverted = np.invert(th1)
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original'),plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(inverted,cmap='gray')
plt.title('Threshold'),plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

[image: Modified Image]
[image: Original Image]

Comment: two thresholds. one for the background (seems to be perfect black anyway), and one for your actual data. then just compose the masks (per-element boolean operations) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp9fV.png

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

Assuming the circle in your images stays in one spot throughout your image set you can manually create a black 'mask' image with a white hole in the middle, then overlay it on the final inverted image.

You can easily make the mask image using your favorite image editor's magic wand tool.

I made this<sup>1</sup> by also expanding the circle inwards by one pixel to take into account some of the pixels the magic wand tool couldn't catch.

[image: Mask]

You would then use the mask image like this:

```py
mask = cv2.imread('/path/to/mask.png')
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(inverted, inverted, mask=mask)
```

## Method 2

If the circle does NOT stay is the same spot throughout your entire image set you can try to make the mask from all the fully black pixels in your original image. This assumes that the 'sample' itself (the thing with the cracks) does not contain fully black pixels. Although this will result in the text on the bottom left to be left white.

```py
# make all the non black pixels white
_,mask = cv2.threshold(gray,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The original is not the same size as your inverted image and thus the mask I made won't actually fit, you're gonna have to make it yourself.</sup>